# How to color the cells of an excel of output conditionally in python?

Tags: python, xls, pandas.excelwriter

I have to color cell of my xls output (only for determinate columns) in this way:

```
green positive value
gray NaN value
red negative valute
```

Suppese my data frame:

```
df
     a   b    c    d    e
0    2   8   -8    3   -4
1   -4   2    9    0    NaN
2    1   0    NaN  8    0
3    5   1    7    1    3
4    6   0   -2    4   -2
```

column ti colorate: a, c and e.

My actually code is simply:

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx')
df.to_excel(writer,'Sheet1', index=False)
writer.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function to do the highlighting...

```
def color_cells():
    # put your condition here
    return ['background-color: yellow']
```

And then apply your highlighting

```
df.style.apply(color_cells)
```

Look at [this](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/style.html) document for more information

For example you can highlight max value :

```
def highlight_max(s):
    '''
    highlight the maximum in a Series yellow.
    '''
    is_max = s == s.max()
    return ['background-color: yellow' if v else '' for v in is_max]
```

You can define your own condition